# Issue with trying to get desired effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I'm trying to create some minimal designs for my sites future administration panel. And if you look [here](http://terrytacey.me/create-post.html), that's the working version of my current code. What I have is the navigation on the left side that slides out and pushes the rest of the pages content towards the right and hides the overflow. Where you enter post content, a textarea, is where I'm encountering my problem. If You enter a enough text that the page scrolls since I have the title and tag input fields set to absolute they stay where they are. Setting them as fixed and adding some margins does make it so they scroll with the page and look nice like that, but if you slide out the navigation the fixed elements won't move. In order to get them to do that I have to move them along with the actual main container, then a scroll bar appears on the x-axis and trying to set `overflow-x: hidden;` on various elements pertaining to those elements does nothing. Here are my html and css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>New Post</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/create-post.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/jquery.tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="main">
        <section>
            <a href="#" class="menu-toggle fa fa-bars"></a>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="logo">Lithium CMS</li>
                    <div class="links">
                        <a href="index.html"><li>Dashboard</li></a>
                        <a href="index.html"><li>Messages</li></a>
                        <a href="index.html"><li>Posts</li></a>
                        <a href="index.html"><li>Pages</li></a>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>

        <section class="content">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="post-title" class="post-title" placeholder="Title...">
                <div class="post-content-container">
                    <textarea name="post-content" class="post-content" placeholder="What you waiting for, start typing!"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="post-tags-container">
                    <input name="post-tags" class="post-tags">
                </div>
            </form>
        <section>

        </section>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function() {
                $('.main').toggleClass('menu-open');
                return false;
            });

            $('.post-content').autogrow();

            $('.post-tags').tagsInput({
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '',
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS

```
    html,
    body {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .main {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    }

    .menu-toggle {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-right: 1px solid #111111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 11px;

    text-align: center;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    }

    .menu-open .menu-toggle {
    left: 210px;
    z-index: 4;
    }

    .menu-open {
    left: 210px;
    }

    .menu-open .menu {
    left: 0;
    }

       .menu,
       .menu-toggle,
       .main {
        -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
        -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
        transition: left 0.2s ease;
       }

   .menu {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-right: 1px solid #111111;
    color: #ffffff;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -210px;
    z-index: 3;


    height: 100%;
    width: 210px;
    }

    .menu li.logo {
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
    }

    .menu a {
    color: #eaeaea;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    }

    .menu a li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2a2a2a;

    padding: 10px;

    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    .menu .links li:hover {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    }

    .content {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }


    .post-title,
    .post-content {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        padding: 15px;

        outline: none;

        width: 100%;
    }

    .post-content {
        resize: none;
    }

    .post-title {
        background-color: #eaeaea;

        font-size: 24px;

        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    .post-content-container {
        max-height: 90%;
    }

    .post-tags-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;

        width: 100%;
    }

    div.tagsinput { border:0px; background: #eaeaea; padding:15px; overflow-y: auto;}
    div.tagsinput span.tag { border: 1px solid #888888; -moz-border-radius:2px; -webkit-border-radius:2px; display: block; float: left; padding: 5px; text-decoration:none; background: #cccccc; color: #333333; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom:5px; font-size:13px;}
    div.tagsinput span.tag a { font-weight: bold; color: #333333; text-decoration:none; font-size: 11px;  } 
    div.tagsinput input { width:80px; margin:0px; font-size: 13px; border:1px solid transparent; padding:5px; background: transparent; color: #333333; outline:0px;  margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; }
    div.tagsinput div { display:block; float: left; } 
    .tags_clear { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0px; }
    .not_valid {background: #FBD8DB !important; color: #90111A !important;}
```

Comment: Broken link, man :/ Also, add relevant CSS/JS/HTML code to the question *itself*.

Comment: Sorry man I fixed it. Also I'm new to stack overflow, I'm not exactly sure what code would be exactly relevant other than those 3 files. I'll edit my post with them though.

Comment: If you fixed it, do other people the favor and post your solution as an answer so other people can solve similar problems too :)

Comment: By fixing it I was talking about the link. lmao

Comment: how can I either get the tags and title inputs to work like it's fixed but not create the unnecessary page scrolling on the x axis. Or is there a way I can set height of the textarea to be in between the title and the tags input, and make the text area scroll if it reaches a percent max-height or something. I'm currently using a jQuery plugin to automatically resize the textarea, I've gone through it and it's docs and haven't found anything that will help me to a great extent.

Comment: Have you tried putting *.post-tags-container* just before `</body>`?

Comment: Wow, so simple, thank you for the help xp. Also thank you for not being a dick. I was told that people on here mostly are haha. Do you know how I can set this as answered?

Comment: No problem, man :) I just added this as an answer. Just click on the `check` mark to the left of it to mark it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem quite easy. Just put *.post-tags-container* right before the end of the body (right before `</body>`).